# java jsoup get text fail

Tags: java, jsoup

I am very new in java jsuop

I want to get the last price in follow line:
http://www.aastocks.com/en/forex/quote/quote.aspx?symbol=NZDHKD&process=y

and i have the follow code:

Elements answerers = document.select("div.content div.inline_block.vat.float_l div.boxForex div.font26 span.neg");

But it return an error:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

I think i am wrong at the  "document.select" part, can someone help me?
Many thanks.

Comment: No, the exception has nothing to do with the doc.select. It's caused by the get method. Edit your question and add the relevant code.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue? Then please accept it or post a follow up question otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The response from the server takes too long, so the default timeout is reached and an exception is thrown:

> If a timeout occurs, an IOException will be thrown. The default
>   timeout is 3 seconds (3000 millis).

So just set a higher [timeout](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#timeout-int-):

**Example Code**

```
String url = "http://www.aastocks.com/en/forex/quote/quote.aspx?symbol=NZDHKD&process=y";
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36";

try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent).timeout(5000).get();
    System.out.println(doc.select("div.content div.inline_block.vat.float_l div.boxForex div.font26 span.neg").first().text());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output**

```
5.6813
```